# Gathering data for evaluating website's accessibility, and evaluating it

Tags: javascript, accessibility

Is anyone aware of any kind of ressources (projects, books, academic papers, etc) on inspecting a website's accessibility with javascript? (fully ajaxified websites, otherwise it wouldn't be possible with the precision I wish). I'm especially interested in evaluating the anchor paths followed by the visitor (read: graph theory).

Note: I won't have control over the visitors' behavior, nor will they be instructed on what they have to do. I'll evaluate it "out in the wild".

Thanks.

Comment: Can Google Analytics help here?  Is that what you mean?

Comment: No. Analytics won't help me reconstruct the graph, nor will it tell me which visitor did what. I need fine-grained data which can be trusted to a very high percentage (thus it will be fully ajaxified).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Analytics can be extended using [API](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/analytics/)